# How are these photos got same color flavor and look so similar?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, light, saturation

I'm trying to understand, how [all these photos](https://www.instagram.com/mikutas/) got the same color flavor. The main problem I see - they are all shot under very different lighting conditions - like inside of a flat and on a sunny beach.

I think:

1. It can't be simply hue and saturation settings from Photoshop.
2. It can't be the same Lightroom preset - because of the different lighting conditions.

Please point me to the right direction: how to make photos, like from the beach and from the inside of a flat to match color so well?

Comment: Answering questions on post production is not easy, especially when you've essentially thrown a portfolio at us and asked, "how do I get this look?" Please select one or two photos max to make your point. Please also describe in as many words possible what "color flavor" is or means to you. Finally, if you'd be so kind as to add an image to this page from which to work so that answers can use it as a before image, post the after image, and explain the steps taken to get there...At which point, you learn!

Comment: ¿Bright, low saturation, high contrast, bluish?

Comment: Do you want to do this in camera or on computer?  What camera do you use?

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871) and [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Comment: @Hueco Good point with two fotos, i'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Those images have one thing in common. That is the warm color tone and also the neutral whites. Take a look at this image:

[Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Z4baaIZn3/)

Did you ever see a gray sky like this? To achieve this look I would go to the HSL section in the develop tab in lightroom and set the saturation of cooler colors to a small value. I would not set them to 0 because then you will end up with a black & white look.

However I dont think they are all edited with only one preset. Some images share low contrast and some others have high contrast. I would try to use the black levels, contrast and saturation of certain colors to achieve some sort of flat look like this.

Answer (score 0):

The comments to the question are well-founded, so what follows is only a hypothesis.

It may have been done in the following manner:

**On location :**
Use of standard parameters, in particular concerning the color balance, or better, but more complex, systematic calibration of the balance on a reference test pattern (medium grey card).

**Under Lightroom (or any other software allowing batch corrections)**

- Homogenization e.g. by using the automatic
- adjustment function but probably also some manual adjustments Using a LUT profile

Whatever, nice work showing a very sharp mastery of both shooting and development.